# c# VS2022 .NET6 Open Hyperlink (Start Browser with URL)

Tags: c#, hyperlink, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I want to open a Hyperlink from C# (Visual Studio 2022, .NET 6).
Unfortunatelly always an Excepttion is raised, althoug I followed exactly MS's docu:
[Start-Internet-Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/start-internet-browser)
Thanks in advance for your help!,
Jo

This fails:
(Exception FFFF FFFF 8000 4005 / -2147467259 : "{"An error occurred trying to start process 'http://google.com' with working directory '...\net6.0-windows'. File not found."})

```
    private void RichTextBoxMemo_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
    string url =  e.LinkText;
        try { 
             System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Problem with URL: '" + url + "'");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this will help you.

```
var uri = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
var psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
{
    UseShellExecute = true,
    FileName = uri
};
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
```